# Working with views in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

So, I have two files that can be retrieved from a database right now. They contain, as follows:

1. A table of info describing certain items. Essentially, key-value pairs. Something like this:

   ```
    ----------------------------------------------------
   |   id     |    count     |        description       |
   |----------------------------------------------------|
   |    1     |    6         |        description       |
   |   43     |    0         |        description       |
   |   25     |    11        |        description       |
    ----------------------------------------------------
   ```
2. A map from collections to ids:

   ```
    -----------------------
   |   collection |   ids  |
   |-----------------------|
   |        a     |  1,10  |
   |        b     |  25,43 |
   |        c     |        |
    -----------------------
   ```

*(This is almost certainly an unclear title, but I'm not sure what I'm missing here.)*

I want to create a page, such that I can view essentially what is in the second table (which is fairly straightforward). I'd like to be able to click one of the collection ids in the second table and go to a page that displays only the relevant lines from the first table.

That is, you'd click on b, and you'd see :

```
 ----------------------------------------------------
|   id     |    count     |        description       |
|----------------------------------------------------|
|   43     |    0         |        description       |
|   25     |    11        |        description       |
 ----------------------------------------------------
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this, and I'd like some pointers.

The data is currently stored in some `yaml` files, but I can store it any way I want, really. I'm using rails for this project. This feels like it should be easy, and I'm just not understanding views in rails properly.

Can I create some sort of model that would apply for each of the ids and display some set of them at the same time? This feels like the most convenient solution, as it would probably allow for me to have hard links to an id.

Comment: Just to get things straight: is there a reason you are extracting files from a database into yaml and then reading those yaml-files in your Rails app? Why not read the db directly from the app?

Answer (score 0):

If you can create page with RoR you must read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-mvc-architecture). After, you must create object( for example: @data = Post.all ) in controller(action in your controller). This object will have data from database. Last, your view file use this object and show your html code. For example index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Index</h2>
<table>
 <thead>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Desc</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <% @data.each do |d| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= d.id %></td>
      <td><%= d.desc %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

If I didn't understand your question so sorry.